# PayPal Adaptive Payment with DoDirectPayment?

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, website-payment-pro

Can we integrate Paypal Adaptive payment method with DoDirectPayment method of Paypal? So that user can pay to multiple receivers using DoDirectPayment Card Method.

If yes then what should be the variables to be sent to Paypal?

Any example code or any link with explanation will be very helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Those are entirely separate products.  With DDP your only options would be to process separate transactions for each receiver that needs some money from it (which the buyer would see on their credit card statement) or have all the money go into a single account and pay out from that account.

Comment: And can we add recurring with Dodirectpayment? So that user can pay amount using credit card from website and also can it can be recurring payment.

Comment: You would have to add Recurring Payments on top of Payments Pro.  You would end up paying $60/mo for this on top of transaction fees, but yes, you can then do what you're wanting.  Instead of using DoDirectPayment, though, you would use CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile.

Comment: Alright Thank you this help Andrew.